# Passing data between activities returns empty string

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-activity

I've found some problems when trying to pass some data from one activity to another.

I get data from an EditText like this:

```
et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et10);
id=et.getText().toString();
```

In the first activity (TakeSomeData.class):

```
Intent i = new Intent(TakeSomeData.this, HttpExample.class);   
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", id );
startActivity(i);
```

In the second Activity (HttpExample.class):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
newString = extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
```

And then i pass this variable as the argument of a method which is defined like this:

```
public String GetInternetData(String str) throws Exception {...}
```

I call this method like this:

```
String returned = test.GetInternetData(newString);
```

But in the end, the string seems to be empty. What could be my fault?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: where are you writing the line id=et.getText().toString(); and when you want to move to another activity??

Comment: public String GetInternetData(String str) throws Exception {...}, here check your "str" value is empty or having something...

Comment: It will work, I think you doing it on onCreate() guess, Try  getIntent().getStringExtra("STRING_I_NEED");

Comment: If I get it properly you mean the "returned" string is empty??
The it doesn't have to do anything with "newString".
Check what are you doing inside GetInternetData.

Comment: Log the value of the string before passing it and after passing it, just to make sure that the issue is that the activity is not receiving a bundle with the string.

Comment: Solved by changing the position of id=et.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving to another activity on a button click or some click events then you need to get the string value from the edit text in that event and pass the value using the intents